# How to split the Run Tool Window in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm relatively new to IntelliJ IDEA and was wondering whether it would be possible to split the Run Window, so that I have multiple Run views visible at the same time. Which would be convenient when running multiple modules concurrently. Currently they show as tabs in the same region, so I have to switch the tab whenever I want to see the other run log.

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|            Source Code          |
|                                 |
+----------------+----------------+
|                |                |
|     Run 1      |     Run 2      |
|                |                |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: 7 years later there still isn't such feature, but [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130374) is ticket for the feature and you can vote for it to increase priority.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know the [h/v split feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html) is available only for editor tabs. There's also a [split mode](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-modes.html#d1065782e349) for tool windows but it works only for different windows, not for multiple tabs of the same windows, so basically no you can't, and I can't imagine what was the reason behind this choice.

Comment: There is an issue placed about it, vote for it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130374

Comment: @jnovacho I'm sure it would help, but I'm not exactly sure why you're telling me this...

Answer (score 3):

You have to right-click on the terminal tab choose "Move to Editor".
Then in the editor, you can split editor tabs vertically or horizontally to have more than one terminal in a column or row.
Your answer is discussed ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093393/can-i-open-multiple-terminal-windows-in-webstorm-and-how)) as well.

[image: move terminal]

[image: split terminals]

Answer (score 2):

You can't split runs, but you can open build in a terminal and split/stack them in any combination. It's not like a one-click run solution, but can be splited/stacket. Hope somebody found it useful.

Tip: you can copy command from the run tab and paste to the terminal so you don't need to type it.

[image: multy terminals]

IntelliJ Ultimate 2018

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.2.1

[image]