# Can I open multiple terminal windows in WebStorm and how?

Tags: windows, terminal, webstorm

I have WebStorm 2019.2.2 on Windows and I would like to have multiple terminal windows, all simultaneously visible next to each other, not as multiple tabs in one terminal window. It is possible to split the editor window multiple times (see fig. 1) via a right-click menu but I can't find the same for the terminal window (fig. 2).

Is it at all possible to achieve this in current version or do I need to contact JetBrains with a feature request?

[image: WebStorm editor menu]

Firgure 1: Right-click menu for the editor window.

[image: WebStorm terminal menu]

Firgure 2: Right-click menu for the terminal window - no possibility to split.

[image: Required view mode]

Firgure 3: This is the layout I would like to achieve with the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and No at the same time.

---

#### No

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141172 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

#### Yes

Have more than Terminal session/tab, then right click and choose "Move to Editor":

[image]

Final result (after few doing few actions):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick! Whoever finds your accepted answer in the far future is free to follow the link you provided to check the status of the corresponding feature request :)